# How to get a Smooth Camera Rotation via button press in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, camera, rotation

I'm relatively new to Unity so my experience in writing code is limited.

I made a camera script that upon button press, rotates the camera on the y-axis, relative to the world space. It works, but its instantaneous. Without affecting its rotation speed or the other axes, I want to show a smooth rotation to its target axis. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float camRotationSpeed = 90f;
    float camRotation;


    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        RotateCamera();
    }

    void RotateCamera()
    {
        camRotation = Input.GetAxis("Camera Rotate") * camRotationSpeed;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Camera Rotate")) 
        {
            gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, camRotation, 0, Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use **[Quaternion.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html)** in order to smooth your rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these kinds of tasks, I would suggest you use tweeting libraries. These quite a few libraries on [Unity Asset-Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/?q=Tween&orderBy=1) some of them are free to use. Since I only used [DoTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676) I can only tell you about that.

You can also achieve this by using CoRoutines as well. But they tend to be memory intensive sometimes.

**Solution:**

```
float camRotationDuration = 0.5f; //This value is in seconds
bool isCameraRotating = false;
void RotateCamera()
{
    camRotation = Input.GetAxis("Camera Rotate") * camRotationSpeed;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Camera Rotate")) 
    {
        if (!isCameraRotating)
        {
            transform.DORotate(new Vector3(0, camRotation , 0), camRotationDuration);
            isCameraRotating = true;
            Invoke("SetCameraRotateToFalse", camRotationDuration);
        }
    }
}

private void SetCameraRotateToFalse()
{
    isCameraRotating = false;
}
```

Please take a look at the DoTween documentation that I've added to the bottom of the answer in case you want to use this.

Reference: 
[DoTween Documentation](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php)

Comment: I just found out I can unhinge the camera from exact coordinates if I spam the rotate button. Is there a way to clamp it so it maintains its coordinates?

Comment: I edited the answer, that will stop you from spamming